# How do you add a new conditional column with the following logic applied at each row: if B[i] = A[i] then print C[i] else print B[i] in R dataframe

Tags: r, replace, logic, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out the proper way to implement code to create a new column in R (Mut) with the following condition:

if RareNuc[i] = Ref[i] then Frequencies$Mut <- CommNuc[i],

else Frequencies$Mut <-RareNuc[i].

**Starting Data Frame:**

```
> Frequencies
RareNuc Ref CommNuc
A   A   A
A   A   A
C   C   C
C   C   C
T   T   T
T   T   T
G   G   G
G   G   A
T   C   C
G   G   A
A   A   G
T   C   C
G   G   A
C   C   A
T   G   G
T   C   C
A   C   C
A   A   G
```

**Ideal Output:**

```
> Frequencies
RareNuc Ref CommNuc Mut
A   A   A   A
A   A   A   A
C   C   C   C
C   C   C   C
T   T   T   T
T   T   T   T
G   G   G   G
G   G   A   A
T   C   C   T
G   G   A   A
A   A   G   G
T   C   C   T
G   G   A   A
C   C   A   A
T   G   G   T
T   C   C   T
A   C   C   A
A   A   G   G
```

I have been at this for some time, and this is the closest thing I have to working.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Frequencies))
{
  if (match(Frequencies$RareNuc[i], Frequencies$Ref[i])) 
  {Frequencies$Mut[i] <- Frequencies$RareNuc[i]}
  else {Frequencies$Mut[i] <- Frequencies$CommNuc[i]}
}
```

In the first rows of Frequencies$Mut it appears to work, however, the column Frequencies$Mut starts to output only A once the columns RareNuc, Ref, & CommNuc no longer all match.

**This error is also produced:**

> Error in if (match(Frequencies$RareNuc[i], Frequencies$Ref[i])) { : 
>     argument is not interpretable as logical

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with base-R `ifelse`:

```r
Frequencies$Mut <- ifelse(Frequencies$RareNuc == Frequencies$Ref,
                          Frequencies$CommNuc, 
                          Frequencies$RareNuc)
Frequencies
#>     RareNuc Ref CommNuc Mut
#>  1:       A   A       A   A
#>  2:       A   A       A   A
#>  3:       C   C       C   C
#>  4:       C   C       C   C
#>  5:       T   T       T   T
#>  6:       T   T       T   T
#>  7:       G   G       G   G
#>  8:       G   G       A   A
#>  9:       T   C       C   T
#> 10:       G   G       A   A
#> 11:       A   A       G   G
#> 12:       T   C       C   T
#> 13:       G   G       A   A
#> 14:       C   C       A   A
#> 15:       T   G       G   T
#> 16:       T   C       C   T
#> 17:       A   C       C   A
#> 18:       A   A       G   G
```

Answer (score 0):

A data.table solution:

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(Frecuencies)[, mut := ifelse(RareNuci == Ref, CommNuci, Ref)]
```